# match or when nothing to match leave blank

Tags: regex

I have logs in format like:

```
Sep 22 12:46:39 10.9.0.203 hotspot,debug Hotspot_account: T-34:23:BA:75:C6:7E (10.40.0.135): some action
```

and:

```
Sep 22 12:46:39 10.9.0.203 hotspot,error,info,debug Hotspot_account: T-34:23:BA:75:C6:7E (10.40.0.135): some action: detailed info about action
```

My regex:

```
^.*[^\:]*\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d[^\:]*?\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s(?P<service>\w+),(?P<severity>\w+)(.+?):\s(?P<mac>\S+)\s.(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(.+?) (?P<action>.+)[\(:,\-].(?P<message>[\w\s]+)
```

catch second one like I want, now I need to modify it to when it's nothing after action to leave field "message" empty, and when after action is some detailed information to put it into field "message" like it is doing now.

Is that possible, or should I use 2 separate regexes to handle both type of messages?

Comment: I guess you are looking for [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/nM1sJ5/2), please check.

Comment: @stribizhev yes, it solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: Great, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add an alternation at the end of the pattern to match either the end of line (`$` in multiline mode) or the message. This alternation will only work if you make the `(?P<action>.+)` lazy (i.e. `(?P<action>.+?)`).

Here is an updated regex:

```
^.*[^:]*\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d[^:]*?\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s(?P<service>\w+),(?P<severity>\w+)(.+?):\s(?P<mac>\S+)\s.(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(.+?) (?P<action>.+?)(?:$|[(:,-].(?P<message>[\w\s]+))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM1sJ5/2) (in demo, I need to use `^.*[^:\n]` in the beginning for demo purposes).